# Gitolite user/repositories management

Tags: git, configuration, gitolite

I have gitolite server running just fine. The number of git repositories is increasing every week. My gitolite.conf was getting messy so I decided to use aliases. however, there is something which I cannot understand.

I have following config:

```
    @users  = u1 u2 u3
    @admins = a1 a2
    @repos  = repo1 repo2 repo3
```

In the easiest scenario I grant RW+ access to @users and R access @admins with following config:

```
   repo @repos
     RW+ = @users
     R   = @admins
```

Now, I would like to deny access to repos *repo1* and *repo2* for user *u1* but give RW+ access to *repo3* .

How would I achieve this gitolite.conf ?

Of course I would prefer not splitting repositories configured in *@repos* alias.